# Issue applying agile methodologies

Tags: agile, scrum, cp

When using an agile methodology on a team programming project, what should be done when several people needs to work in something that is to be used by everyone. For example, There is a User entity, and two people have to do requirements that need to use that entity. So, first an skeleton is created and then the activities are assigned? or what is the procedure in these cases.

And second, Is it possible to find information that addresses this kind of issues that can occur when applying such methodologies?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing about Scrum, is that it is an amazing tool for identifying **bad practices**. This is one of the cases. An agile team should be working with as many hands as possible, on the **same** requirement (requirement, feature, user story - same thing). The division of work between members should be based on the **tasks** needed to complete the requirement, no the requirements themselves.

Each task would be defined based on the modifications that need to be made to a certain component. Doing that will not only make the problem go away (nobody's working on the same code), but will unite the team members' efforts, and make them function as a real team, rather than a disparate group of individuals that happen to share a room and a manager.

As for official information on the subject, I can suggest reading any book about Scrum, but you might want to focus on the following sites:

- [Introduction to Scrum](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/topics/scrum)
- [Mike Cohn's Blog](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/)
- [Scrum.org](http://www.scrum.org/)

A few great books:

- [Succeeding with Scrum - Mike Cohn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321579364)
- **Free ebook** - [Scrum & XP from the Trenches - Henrik Kniberg](http://www.crisp.se/henrik.kniberg/ScrumAndXpFromTheTrenches.pdf)

And finally, if you pardon the shameless plug, you can check out my blog - I have a few posts on this subject (such as [this one](http://www.softwareandi.com/2012/01/10-signs-that-your-team-isnt-really.html)) and others from my experience about implementing agile methods in software teams.

Comment: This is what I was expecting. Thank you very much!!!